# Name for a certain type of derived category similar to $(\mathbf{C}\downarrow\mathbf{C})$

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

$\newcommand{Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$

Consider a category $\mathbf{C}$, and draw a graph according to the following rules:

1. Place all objects onto the graph
2. Between every two objects $A,B\in\operatorname{obj}(\mathbf{C})$, if $\Hom(A,B)\neq\emptyset$, draw an arrow between $A, B$. Take that arrow to represent the *entire hom-set* of morphisms between $A$ and $B$.
3. Now take the line-graph of the above graph and use it to define a category $\mathbf{C}^\prime$, whose objects are *collections* of morphisms in $\mathbf{C}$.

Perhaps more clearly, suppose that commutative squares like the following occur in $\mathbf{C}$:

$$
\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} 
A @>{f}>> A^\prime\\ 
@VV{h}V @VV{h^\prime}V \\
B @>{f^\prime}>> B^\prime \end{CD}$$

Then we take the entire hom-sets $\Hom(A,B), \Hom(A^\prime,B^\prime)$ to be objects $H, H^\prime$ respectively in $\mathbf{C^\prime}$. Furthermore, $F=\langle f, f^\prime\rangle$ is a morphism in $\mathbf{C^\prime}$; in general, a  morphism $\langle f, f^\prime\rangle$ exists in $\Hom(H,H^\prime)$ iff there exists a pair of arrows $h\in H, h^\prime\in H^\prime$ so as to make the above diagram commute. In that regard, $F\circ G$ is meaningful iff the targets of $f,f^\prime$ are respectively the domains of $g,g^\prime$; in other words if both pairs share an object each. In that sense the objects of $\mathbf{C}$ define the morphisms of $\mathbf{C^\prime}$, thus the identification with the line graph of the diagram of $\mathbf{C}$.

In particular and for example, if $\mathbf{C}$ is preadditive, then all objects in $\mathbf{C^\prime}$ are additive abelian groups, and the morphisms $\mathbf{C^\prime}$ are all group homomorphisms.

Now, it's entirely possible I'm misunderstanding what comma categories are; but as I understand it, the category $(\mathbf{C}\downarrow\mathbf{C})$ has as its objects *individual morphisms* of $\mathbf{C}$, which isn't quite what I'm looking for. Am I wrong? If not, is there an existing name for categories as I've described them above?

Comment: I don't understand your step 3 at all. What are the objects and morphisms of $C'$? You say "collections of morphisms" - which collections?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Actually, probably a simpler way to state it would be: the objects of $\mathbf{C}^\prime$ are the hom-sets of $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Okay. What are the morphisms?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Roughly speaking, defined the same way they are in comma categories -- as commuting squares -- except that again, we batch together all such morphisms together into a single hom-set.

Comment: More precisely, suppose we have the diagram $$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> A^\prime\\
@VV{h}V @VV{h^\prime}V \\
B @>{g}>> B^\prime
\end{CD}
$$
Then $H=\{h\}=\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ and $H^\prime=\{h^\prime\}=\operatorname{Hom}(A^\prime,B^\prime)$ are objects in $\mathbf{C}^\prime$, and for each $h\in H,h^\prime\in H^\prime$, if there exists an $f,g$ that makes the above square commute, then $\langle f,g\rangle$ is a morphism in $\operatorname{Hom}(H, H^\prime)$ in $\mathbf{C}^\prime$.

Comment: Okay. What is the composition? I don't understand why you're collapsing together all the homs like this (as far as I can tell this prevents composition from being well-defined). The closest construction to this that I can think of is the arrow category (which is the comma category $C \downarrow C$): https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category

Comment: I guess step 2 is a [change of base functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/change+of+enriching+category) from a Set-category to a Bool-category. (I haven't checked that works.) Then step 3 would just be forming the arrow category for the resulting Bool-category.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to consider the category where every object $B$ is repeated as many times as many homsets $\hom(A,B)$ are nonempty.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It is rather arrow-category-esque, isn't it? But arrow categories don't do the batching that I need. W.r.t. composition, since $f,g$ are "really" just arrows between *objects* of $\mathbf{C}$, they "forget" which specific morphism they're associated with immediately anyway; the composition of two arrows $\langle f, f^\prime\rangle$ and $\langle g, g^\prime\rangle$ is valid iff the targets of $F=\langle f, f^\prime\rangle$ are the domains of $G=\langle g, g^\prime\rangle$, i.e. if the target of $F$ is the domain of $G$, as we'd generally hope.

Comment: I think this is sort of 2-category-esque, but I'm unsure? At any rate, I'm doing the batching because I need the hom-object structure in my derived category -- I'd like to derive a category whose objects are collections of morphisms with structure, a sort of "power category" derived from power-sets of sets of morphisms that happen to retain a particular structure.

Comment: @Nathaniel Hmm... I think that would almost work? But I do need to retain some idea of how 'big' the original hom-sets were, because otherwise I might get initial/terminal/zero objects that I don't want, I think, since the number of arrows is capped at one anyway.

Comment: The way you've defined morphisms, there can be a morphism $\langle f,g\rangle$ from $H=\text{Hom}(A,B)$ to $H'=\text{Hom}(A',B')$ and a morphism $\langle f',g'\rangle$ from $H'$ to $H''=\text{Hom}(A'',B'')$, but no morphisms from $H$ to $H''$. So there is no possible definition of composition that makes this a category. The problem is that there may not be a single map $h':A'\to B'$ that fits into both a commutative square involving $\langle f,g\rangle$ and a commutative square involving $\langle f',g'\rangle$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard AFAIK, arrows are not required to be 'total functions' (and I'm not entirely sure how you'd define that without reference to substructure). So there doesn't need to be a $h^\prime$ shared between the two; only an $h_1^\prime$ mapped onto by $\langle f, g \rangle$ and an $h_2^\prime$ mapped out of by $\langle f^\prime, g^\prime \rangle$, for the composition to at least be well-defined.

Comment: Coming at it the other way, since $\mathbf{C}$ is a valid category, if $\exists (f:A\to A^\prime), (f^\prime:A^\prime\to A^{\prime\prime})$ then $\exists f^{\prime\prime}: A\to A^{\prime\prime} = f^\prime \circ f$, and similarly $\exists (g:B\to B^\prime), (g^\prime:B^\prime\to B^{\prime\prime})\implies\exists g^{\prime\prime}: B\to B^{\prime\prime}=g^\prime\circ g$; so together $\langle f^{\prime\prime}, g^{\prime\prime}\rangle$ must be a morphism in $\mathbf{C^\prime}$ with $\langle f^{\prime\prime}, g^{\prime\prime}\rangle = \langle f^\prime, g^\prime \rangle \circ \langle f, g\rangle$

Comment: Why is $\langle f’’,g’’\rangle$ a morphism? I thought there needed to be a commutative square for that to be the case?

Comment: Hmm... 
$$\require{AMScd} 
\begin{CD} 
A @>{f}>> A^\prime @>{f^\prime}>> A^{\prime\prime}\\ 
@VV{h}V @V{h^\prime_1}V{h^\prime_2}V @VV{h^{\prime\prime}}V \\ 
B @>>{g}> B^\prime @>>{g^\prime}> B^{\prime\prime} 
\end{CD}$$
Okay, I see your point. I think I need to require that the category has all equalizers for this to make sense -- then I think I can conclude that the larger square does in fact commute?